# Is differens different?

Tags: vocabulary, meaning, adjective, participle

I would like to understand the Latin participle *differens* and compare it to the English adjective "different".
The verb [*differre*](http://latinlexicon.org/definition.php?p1=2017194) means roughly "to carry apart", but [Lewis Elementary](http://latinlexicon.org/definition.php?p1=1004735) also lists "to be different" among the translations.
With this meaning it seems that *differens* can mean "different".

I got the feeling that the meanings of *differens* and "different" overlap, but neither includes the other.
It seems that if I want to say "different", I should probably try some other word than *differens* first, like *dissimilis*.
Is this correct, or should I look at it some other way?
How would you compare *differens* and "different"?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, in my opinion that is correct. While differens is sometimes used as different, the literal translation of different is dissimilis (which is reflected in other latin-derived languages). Generally differens is used as "superior" or "excellent", in the sense that it is set apart from everything else for that reason.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Do you have sources or quotes you can add to support your points?